# How to develop and debug angular apps in docker

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run an angular app in a docker container, but I lack knowledge on what is typically running where. Let me start with what I have:

- a hello world angular app, running in docker, started through docker compose
- vscode with debugger for firefox
- vscode with remote development

I build and run the following dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app/package.json

RUN npm install --force
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

COPY . /app

CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

and I run it via below docker compose file `docker-compose up --build`

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: webapp/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    volumes:
      - ./webapp:/app

volumes:
  webapp:
```

When I open firefox and browse to http://localhost:4200, my hello world app is running. So it's working up till this part. But then the debugging part....

Before I tried to dockerize things, I just launched the app on node.js through vscode using this launch.json

```
{
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "ng serve",
      "type": "firefox",
      "reAttach": true,
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200/",
      "tmpDir": "./.firefox-temp"
    },
  ]
}
```

But now I no longer want to launch npm: start since the app is already running. I just want to attach the debugger. And I have a hard time finding some guidance online. I've tried the following resources to get this to work:

- https://gparlakov.medium.com/debugging-angular-framework-running-inside-docker-container-using-vs-code-79a04d814d82
- [How to debug Angular app in a Docker container Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466651/how-to-debug-angular-app-in-a-docker-container-visual-studio-code)
- consulted my dear friend, chat gpt, but he's not very certain about his own suggestions after I asked a couple of follow up questions.

Am I looking in the wrong direction and is it not really "common" to debug angular apps running in docker? Or am I actually rather close and can somebody guide me through this a bit?

I am very eager to learn:

- When debugging an angular app in docker, where is the debugger really running? On my host PC or indeed inside the docker container? (since websites typically render client side, I assumed the debugger runs on the host, but can imagine both ways)
- I like the idea of developing/debugging angular in docker, but if this is a bad idea, I'd love to hear that
- Where to find the real "not outdated" documentation

Comment: Do you actually need an isolation system like Docker in this setup?  Or can you run Node without Docker directly on the host, and delete the first two files you show?

Comment: I can run node on my host, that's what I am currently am doing. But I'd like to "not need node installed on host" and just fire up all docker containers and attach to backend (already works) and attach to angular app in docker (not working yet, not exactly sure how to do this either)